# Adapting to Spring security 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Due to a migration to Spring security 6 and the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecation  I need to adapt the security conf below, buit not sure if I am going in the correct way.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Inject
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v1/**", "/v2/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v3/polls/**").authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .realmName("Quick Poll")
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable();
  }
 }
```

I tried so far this below but not sure it is correct:

```
 @Configuration
 public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining step is to replace `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure` with a `SecurityFilterChain` bean.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/v1/**", "/v2/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**")
            .permitAll().requestMatchers("/v3/polls/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic().realmName("Quick Poll")
            .and().csrf().disable().build();
}
```

Comment: @jacknik Is your `UserDetailsService` also registered as a bean/component?

Comment: My god . . . forgot to set it up as bean, now works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> **It supports Spring security 6.1 to latest. Even you'll no longer able**
> **to use this version of configuration rather then lambda.**

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            // .cors(withDefaults()) // To apply
            // .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((rm) -> rm
                    .requestMatchers("/v1/**", "/v2/**",
                            "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**"
                    ).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/v3/polls/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().denyAll() // If you try denied others
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .httpBasic(basic-> basic.realmName("Quick Poll"))
            .build();
}
```